# `useMemo` do not work as expected, it introduce an infinite lopp

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router'
import { getTokenList } from './tokenList'
import wrapPromise from '../lib/wrapPromise'

const store = {}
export default function usePair(pairId) {
  const { chain } = useParams()

  //work as expected *****FIRST*****
  if (!store[pairId]) {
    store[pairId] = wrapPromise(
      getTokenList(chain).then(({ tokenMap }) => {
        console.log(tokenMap[pairId])
        return tokenMap[pairId]
      })
    )
  }
  
  //infinite loop ****SECOND****
  store[pairId] = useMemo(
    () =>
      wrapPromise(
        getTokenList(chain).then(({ tokenMap }) => {
          console.log(tokenMap[pairId])
          return tokenMap[pairId]
        })
      ),
    [chain, pairId]
  )

  return pairId ? store[pairId]() : undefined
}
```

As far as I know, about react, the FIRST and SECOND are exactly the same, but they do not actually. The first work as expected, the second introduces an infinate loop

Comment: Most likely, your component which uses this hook has setState in it which updates the component in turns calling this hook over and over again. Try placing your API calls inside `React.useEffect`.

Comment: @PrateekThapa ignores the fact outside the code example. `useMemo` and `closure` should have exactly the same effect, isn't it. So in which way they are not equivalent?

Comment: what is `chain` parameter?

Comment: @Guichi I don't get what you mean though. Can you create a reproducible issue?

Comment: @PrateekThapa It does not matter the context. The problem is `closure VS useMemo` behave differently, which is beyond my expectation

Comment: @Guichi  Could you exactly elaborate what `closure vs useMemo` behaviour are you talking about? I find it interesting. We never had that issue before.

Comment: @PrateekThapa In React, `useMemo/useRef/useCallback` basically do the same thing as `closure`. i.e. keep the state somewhere outside the function scope, so that the function returns yet the state keep. In the first example,  `store` is external to function, so I can keep the state, same effect should be achieved by `useMemo` in a normal sense. `wrapPromise` is actually something related to `suspense` unstable API which may have bugs to break such assumption